# error with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter when migrating springboot application 2.7 to 3.1.1

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

Good afternoon, I have a problem with an application in springboot 2.7.1 that I updated to version 3.1.1
my application uses CustomOpaqueTokenIntrospector to validate a token, the problem is that in version 3.1.1 "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter", "cors","antMatchers", "oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken()" are deprecated, and honestly I'm new to this authentication and authorization.
Could you help me with an answer on how I could correct my problem, I have attached the code of my configuration classes.

**Class OpaqueSecurityConfig:**

```
package ec.edu.espe.generalapi.Config.security;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.OpaqueTokenIntrospector;

@Configuration
public class OpaqueSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       
        http.cors();
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authz -> authz
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/public/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/apiGeneral-docs/**", "swagger-ui-GeneralApi/**", "/swagger-ui-GeneralApi.html/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken();
    }

    @Bean
    OpaqueTokenIntrospector tokenIntrospector(RestTemplateBuilder builder, OAuth2ResourceServerProperties resourceServerProps) {
        return new CustomOpaqueTokenIntrospector(builder, resourceServerProps);
    }

}
```

**Class CustomOpaqueTokenIntrospector:**

```
package ec.edu.espe.generalapi.Config.security;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.OpaqueTokenIntrospector;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;

import java.time.Duration;


public class CustomOpaqueTokenIntrospector implements OpaqueTokenIntrospector {
    private OAuth2ResourceServerProperties.Opaquetoken opaqueTokenProps;
    private RestTemplateBuilder builder;
    CustomOpaqueTokenIntrospector(RestTemplateBuilder builder, OAuth2ResourceServerProperties resourceServerProps) {
        this.opaqueTokenProps = resourceServerProps.getOpaquetoken();
        this.builder = builder;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal introspect(String token) {
      //  System.out.println(token);
        RestOperations restOperations = builder
                .defaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .build();
        return new NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector(opaqueTokenProps.getIntrospectionUri(), restOperations).introspect(token);
    }
}
```

and finally:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.7.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.12'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-security:1.6.12'
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.3.1'
    runtimeOnly 'com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:9.2.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.6.1'
    runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is in migration and nothing else, i mean to replace old configuration.

You should remove  `extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

The configuration class will look so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OpaqueSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)  throws Exception {

    http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
      request.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
              "/public/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/apiGeneral-docs/**", "swagger-ui-GeneralApi/**", "/swagger-ui-GeneralApi.html/**").permitAll()
          .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/**").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated();
    });
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(c -> c.opaqueToken(Customizer.withDefaults()));

    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  OpaqueTokenIntrospector tokenIntrospector(RestTemplateBuilder builder, OAuth2ResourceServerProperties resourceServerProps) {
    return new CustomOpaqueTokenIntrospector(builder, resourceServerProps);
  }

}
```

But i really suggest you to check next resources:

[spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

[Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html)

About `gradle` build file also update the version for

`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:**2.7.0**'` to one that you use in project.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter was deprecated.
Here is how you do it now:
https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter